# What is best for SEO - 'RDFa Semantic Web' or 'Link Building'

Tags: seo, link-building, rdfa

Given that RDFa is fairly sensible and Google use it, should I plug in some sensible semantic web tags into my site or should I invest my energies into link building?

I was also planning to use [this](http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/tools/grsnippetgen/) to put my semantic markup together.

I don't think the site is important to the question, however it is a relaunched hotel website.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you choose one over the other? You should be doing both as the two are not mutually exclusive. Build your site with semantic markup, including rdfa, and then seek links after it is built.

Comment: Sometimes only a certain amount of time is available and I think a lot of the link building 'tricks' that people do are a bit SEO 1.0 cheezy spam. If you have any quality link building articles - or if this is covered elsewhere on SE then let me know.

Comment: Most link building tricks are just that. They "trick" the webmaster into thinking they're building quality links but they aren't. The easier is it to get the link the less value it probably has. I always recommend to dedicate time to creating quality content which attracts links on its own. But in your case a hotel website isn't really going to do that. Link building is definitely going to require effort. I would recommend using the rdfa as it is the best use of time and then seek links with the remaining time left.

Comment: Whatabout sensible links to and ideally from places in the area such as the tea-shops, nature parks, cab firms and anything that tourists might be interested in? Surely that is just sensible stuff to have on the site. What beyond that should/could I do in the way of 'link building'? I don't see being in the Netscape directory any much use...

Comment: Links to other sites aren't really gonna help SEO. It's the incoming links that really matter. But it's good to do for your users as it makes your site more valuable to them which is a good thing. Links from local businesses should help especially as Geolocation becomes more and more important. Most directories carry very little link value so you'll need to get a lot of them before they become useful. Dmoz is probably the best one in terms of having any tangible value. Otherwise any website that is related to hotels in some way is where you need to try to be.

Comment: Agreed that hotel directory listings need to be maintained but I am still not feeling it - nobody has visited Dmoz since 1066 and I don't see how that possibly can be of any use, never mind the nebulous links from worthless link farm sites. Links to other sites in the area - are you sure that is not going to help? There is an opportunity to create definitive content for the area purely from links out to local businesses and some introduction to them - a ready made guide for tourists that may visit. Are you sure I shouldn't bother with 'outgoing links' and go for link-farm spam?

Comment: Dmoz isn't really used anymore but a link from there still has value. In fact it's the most you can get from a standalone directory. It's human value may be zero but its SEO value is more then zero. A link farm and directories are two different things. Directories are good and legit, but rarely very valuable. Link farms are artificial sites created for the sole purpose of manipulating the SERPs. Niche sites can benefit from directory submissions to to their relatively low level of competition.

Comment: Link pages are not quality content and won't do much, if anything, for your rankings. But there's more to websites than SEO so you should do it because it is good for human beings.